# How to create an association in FactoryGirl with a value lazy-evaluated from another FactoryGirl association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

Is it possible to use an association as the value for another association in a trait?

Let me describe a (simplified) example. I have 3 models

- `User`
- `Forum` (`belongs_to :forum`)
- `Thread` (`belongs_to :forum`, `belongs_to :user`)

Please note that `Thread` contains an `user_id`, it does not belong to `User` through `Forum` (at the time being, I can't change such constraint).

What I'd like to know, is if there a way to define a trait like the one

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :thread do
    trait :with_forum do
      association :user
      # Lazy-evaluate the value of user to the previously created factory
      # THIS IS THE KEY POINT: I want 'user' to be the factory created at the previous line
      association :forum, user: user
    end
  end
end
```

What the trait is supposed to do is to create an user and associate it to the thread.
Then it should create a forum, but the user should be the same instance previously created.

There are mainly two reasons:

- The user associated with the forum is the same of the thread
- I don't want to create two user factories on cascade

Any idea? I tried to use the lazy evaluation, but no way to use it with associations.

Answer (score 2):

Does it make sense to do the opposite and set the thread's user to be the same as the forum's? Does the forum factory create a user?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :thread do
    trait :with_forum do
      forum
      user { forum.user }
    end
  end
end
```

If you really want to do it the other way, you can definitely use a lazy attribute:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :thread do
    trait :with_forum do
      user
      forum { create(:forum, user: user) }
    end
  end
end
```

The downside there will be that it will always create a forum regardless of the strategy used to build the thread.

Answer (score 1):

You have to lazily evaluate the `association` call:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :thread do
    trait :with_forum do
      user
      forum { association(:forum, user: user) }
    end
  end
end
```